# Javascript, Calling Java Applet method throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, java, applet

I have a simple Applet class:

```
package com.myapp;

class MyApplet extends Applet {
    public String myMethod() {
       return "Hello";
    }
}
```

I have compiled my with other my java classes into jarfile. Then I have run this jar files main class to ensure that jar is correctly created. It works.

Then I try to embed this Applet into my page:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log(document.MyApplet.myMethod())
    });
</script>

<applet archive="myjar.jar" code="com.myapp.MyApplet.class" id="MyApplet" name="MyApplet" width=100 height=100></applet>
```

This throws me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myMethod' of undefined
```

Which means that `document.MyApplet` returns **undefined**

When I try to call it like this:

```
document.getElementById('MyApplet').myMethod();
```

It throws me this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).myMethod is not a function
```

Did I miss something?

I have tested this on:

1. Chrome 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)
2. Firefox 52.0.2 (32-bit)

Applet was compiled by using `JDK 8`.

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536455/calling-java-method-in-javascript

Comment: @MohamedAbbas this answer is about making ajax requests and it is not connected to my quesion.

Comment: updated answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem behind this task was that **Last versions of Firefox, Chorme and Safari does not support applets and they wont launch them**

The only browser that is still can launch applets is **Internet Explorer** and it also requires explicit permissions which are considered very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    console.log(document.getElementById('MyApplet').myMethod())
```

You can grab elements by `getElementById`

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html) you need to include the following script to run the applet.

```
<script src=
  "https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    <!-- applet id can be used to get a reference to
    the applet object -->
    var attributes = { id:'MyApplet',
        code:'jcom.myapp.MyApplet.class',  width:1, height:1} ;
    var parameters = { jnlp_href: 'MyApplet.jnlp'} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
</script>
```

Comment: I have received `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).myMethod is not a function` error. Do I need to turn something on in my browser?

Comment: hmm .. just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278626/javascript-to-java-applet-communication

Comment: are you sure of the path? try  `archive="./myjar.jar"`

Comment: Still throws same error. My applet in browser has zero width and height even if I set them 100, is it connected with my error?

Comment: width and height even if 0 will still be in the DOM.. can you try `console.log(document.getElementById('MyApplet'))`

Comment: It returns me `<applet archive="myjar.jar" code="com.myapp.MyApplet.class" id="MyApplet" name="MyApplet" width=100 height=100></applet>`